# libarb.so & libflint.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries

I installed [arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/#general-information) and try to run this code:

```
#include "arb.h"

int main()
{
    arb_t x;
    arb_init(x);
    arb_const_pi(x, 50 * 3.33);
    arb_printn(x, 50, 0); printf("\n");
    printf("Computed with arb-%s\n", arb_version);
    arb_clear(x);
}
```

But in terminal I got this error"

```
error while loading shared libraries: libarb.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

I searched and there is a libarb.so in `/usr/local/lib`.

---

**Edit**: 
‌Answers helped me and that error was solved but another one shown now:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libflint.so.13: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There is a link to libflint.so.13 in `/usr/local/lib`, but is seems my QtCreator project cannot access it (probably because its name does not end with .so).

Comment: What commands are you using to compile?  Where did you install `arb` to?

Comment: ./configure  make   make install.

Comment: Please don't add new problems into your question. The answer helped you. All other problems are new questions ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550654/libarb-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 4):

Your `libarb.so` is not in your library path. Check your env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Sometimes helps running

```
ldconfig
```

especially if you installed the library manually.

---

And your second question

The missing file `/usr/lib/libflint.so` is part of the package `libflint-dev`

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install libflint-dev
```

Why? [That's why.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libflint.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)